# Loader / Spinner infinite | Filter Everything Pro

Tags: wordpress, filter, plugins

I install the plugin Filter Everything Pro on Wordpress, and i did menu with bootstrap and my css and just a little js for add and remove class. When i'm in the page without the plugin, everything is ok, but when i'm in the page who the plugin works, the spinner / loader is in infinite and i can't click anywhere. (even if i display:none that div)

Someone have this problem before ? I really don't know where to find the problem.
(i don't have error message in my console / inspector)

Sorry for my english, hope you will understand.

i try to display:none or visibility:hidden but that doesnt work